# Registering codecs for MongoDB using Micronaut

Tags: java, mongodb, micronaut

I'm in the process of creating a new application using Micronaut and MongoDB. I have to a bit of stalemate regarding some of my db objects.

I have an object that contains an enum field which I need to convert over to a value that can be saved (I'm planning to persist it as a string).

From what I understand and from the error message I'm getting, I need to create a new codec to handle this (similar to JPA converters). While I have found examples showing this, I'm a bit confused as to how I'm supposed to register the converter for the MongoClient.

I'm using the latest Micronaut version of both the framework and the respective MongoClient.

Below is the exception I'm getting for reference:

```
org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class fts.marketing.models.CampaignEmailStatus.
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecCache.getOrThrow(CodecCache.java:46)
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:63)
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:37)
    at com.mongodb.client.model.BuildersHelper.encodeValue(BuildersHelper.java:37)
    at com.mongodb.client.model.Filters$SimpleEncodingFilter.toBsonDocument(Filters.java:1109)
    at com.mongodb.client.model.Filters$AndFilter.toBsonDocument(Filters.java:946)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.Operations.createFindOperation(Operations.java:142)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.Operations.find(Operations.java:130)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.AsyncOperations.find(AsyncOperations.java:85)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.FindIterableImpl.createFindOperation(FindIterableImpl.java:229)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.FindIterableImpl.asAsyncReadOperation(FindIterableImpl.java:225)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoIterableImpl.batchCursor(MongoIterableImpl.java:161)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoIterableSubscription.requestInitialData(MongoIterableSubscription.java:46)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.AbstractSubscription.tryRequestInitialData(AbstractSubscription.java:151)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.AbstractSubscription.request(AbstractSubscription.java:84)
    at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.ObservableToPublisher$1$1.request(ObservableToPublisher.java:50)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableToListSingle$ToListSubscriber.onSubscribe(FlowableToListSingle.java:84)
    at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.ObservableToPublisher$1.onSubscribe(ObservableToPublisher.java:39)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoIterableSubscription.<init>(MongoIterableSubscription.java:40)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.Observables$1.subscribe(Observables.java:47)
    at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.ObservableToPublisher.subscribe(ObservableToPublisher.java:36)
    at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.FindPublisherImpl.subscribe(FindPublisherImpl.java:189)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it should be enough to create a class with the codec and have it injectable:

```
@Singleton
public class EnumCodec implements Codec<CampaignEmailStatus> {

  @Override
  public CampaignEmailStatus decode(BsonReader reader, DecoderContext decoderContext) {
    String enumString = reader.readString();
    return CampaignEmailStatus.valueOf(enumString);
  }

  @Override
  public void encode(BsonWriter writer, CampaignEmailStatus value, EncoderContext encoderContext) {
    String enumString = value.name();
    writer.writeString(enumString);
  }

  @Override
  public Class<CampaignEmailStatus> getEncoderClass() {
    return CampaignEmailStatus.class;
  }
}
```

The Mongo driver docs explaining Codecs are here: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.11/bson/codecs/

The injection of the codecs happens here

```
io.micronaut.configuration.mongo.reactive.DefaultReactiveMongoConfiguration#codecs
```

You should be able to debug it from there if it's not working

PS: I did not test the code above but it should give you an idea

Comment: Thank you very much. What you suggested worked very well. I did not think that it would be so easy to do tbh. Pity they do not have examples like these in their documentation.

Comment: @Aris_Kortex Glad it worked for you. Micronaut is an open source framework. You can always provide further documentation if you like. Others will profit from your learnings.

Comment: @Marco For me, this is not working. How did you register codec https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68559101/org-bson-codecs-configuration-codecconfigurationexception-cant-find-a-codec-fo

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB java client is inconsistent about handling enums and it's still not fixed, see [JAVA-2720](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2720).

For enums occuring as object properties there's automatic [`EnumPropertyCodecProvider`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/bson/src/main/org/bson/codecs/pojo/EnumPropertyCodecProvider.java) codec implementation and it works out of the box. However, if you use enum with `com.mongodb.client.model.Filters` it doesn't work and ends up with the exception from the question.

The solution with registering specific enum codec for Micronaut works, but it requires to define one codec bean for each enum you want to handle. Here is more generic solution working for all enums:

```java
@Singleton
public class EnumCodecRegistry implements CodecRegistry {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public <T> Codec<T> get(Class<T> clazz) {
        if (Enum.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
            return new EnumCodec(clazz);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> Codec<T> get(Class<T> clazz, CodecRegistry registry) {
        return get(clazz);
    }

    private static class EnumCodec<T extends Enum<T>> implements Codec<T> {
        private final Class<T> clazz;

        EnumCodec(final Class<T> clazz) {
            this.clazz = clazz;
        }

        @Override
        public void encode(final BsonWriter writer, final T value, final EncoderContext encoderContext) {
            writer.writeString(value.name());
        }

        @Override
        public Class<T> getEncoderClass() {
            return clazz;
        }

        @Override
        public T decode(final BsonReader reader, final DecoderContext decoderContext) {
            return Enum.valueOf(clazz, reader.readString());
        }
    }

}
```